# Get parent Id on checked unchecked event in aciTree

Tags: acitree

I want to ask a question that how can i get the parent id of child node in aciTree. If uservchecked the child node then i want to save its id with its parent id. 
 Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. 
I have gone through aciTree documentation http://acoderinsights.ro/source/aciTree/documentation.html# but didn't found any method to get the parent id on child selection.

```
   if (eventName == 'checked') {
                if (bankUsers.indexOf(api.getId(item)) == -1) {
                    if (api.getId(item) == -2 || api.getId(item) - 3) {
                        bankUsers = new Array();
                        bankUsers[0] = api.getId(item);
                    } else {
                        bankUsers.push(api.getId(item));
                    }
                }
            } else if (eventName == 'unchecked') {
                if (bankUsers.indexOf(api.getId(item)) != -1) {
                    if (api.getId(item) == -2 || api.getId(item) - 3) {
                        bankUsers = new Array();
                    } else {
                        bankUsers.splice(bankUsers.indexOf(api.getId(item)), 1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have found how to get the parent id on child selection.
console.log("ParentId="+api.getId(api.parent(item)));

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function :

```
var parentID = api.itemData(api.parent(item)).id;
```

as simple as this.

if .id give undefiend you can use the following:

```
var parentID = api.getId(api.parent(item));
```